# Adding a 'Add Button' to the actionbar at the top when you already have tabs and a menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, drawable

I'm trying to add an 'Add Item' button at the top in the action bar. (To the right of the App Icon and Title).

Right under the action bar, I have two tabs that I can swipe between. I also have a menu XML file defined for the settings menu.

I thought actionbar uses a menu XML as well. So I added a actionbar menu XML, but when I use

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionbar.setCustomView(R.menu.actionbar);
```

my program crashes. I believe I'm doing this totally incorrectly.

My actionbar XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"></item>


</menu>
```

I read on some tutorials that I'm supposed to add items to the actionbar and populate it via the OnCreateOptionsMenu function in mainActivity. But that's where my options menu is populated, not my actionbar.

Comment: Can you please show your logcat report to help us help you. **Thanks**.

Comment: Do you want a custom `ActionBar` implementation, or do you just want an extra item in the normal `ActionBar`?

Comment: Just an extra item in the normal actionbar. Just the 'add' button up there. I was confused when reading to put it in the OnCreateOptions because that is where I populated and made my options menu (hardware button). If I changed it to use the actionbar, wouldnt it erase the options menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An activity populates the ActionBar in its onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

Instead of using setcustomview(),  just override onCreateOptionsMenu like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

   return true;
}
```

If an actions in the ActionBar is selected, the onOptionsItemSelected() method is called. It receives the selected action as parameter. Based on this information you code can decide what to do for example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuitem1:
           Toast.makeText(this,"Menu Item 1 selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           break;
        case R.id.menuitem2:
           Toast.makeText(this,"Menu item 2 selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           break;
        default:
           break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I already have an OnCreateOptionsMenu in my mainactivity. It's being used for the options menu that pops up when you press the hardware settings button. Would I change R.menu.mainmenu to R.menu.actionbar?

Is there any way to keep both my settings menu AND have the action bar populated?

Comment: Change it to  R.menu.mainmenu in your oncreateoptionsmenu() @CREW